# Get latest commit sha or tag with git

Tags: git

How do I use git to get either the tag of the current commit or, if the tag is not present, the short commit sha?

I have been using `git describe --always`, but it's not working anymore for some reason, it's now returning this last tag weeks old with some random numbers and some sha.

```bash
❯ git describe --always
some-tag-1437-g9d3616e339
```

```bash
❯ git log
9d3616e339 [11 minutes ago] (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) message
# ... bunch of other commits with no tags
81bbfc64e2 [8 weeks ago] (tag: some-tag) message
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: look what is returning on the command executed `some-tag-1437-g9d3616e339`

Comment: It looks like it returned some tag and some commit hash, like you asked for.

Comment: Should return either one or the other. I also have no idea what the `1437` or `g9d3616e339` is.

Comment: `some-tag-1437-g9d3616e339` could be the tag name? May you share the list of tags `git tag --list`?

Comment: "some-tag-1437-g9d3616e339" means "some-tag, 1437 commits since, g for git, object hash 9d3616e339". That's exactly the format shown in [the examples in the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#_examples).

Comment: @IMSoP interesting, I didn't know that, thanks, the `9d3616e339` is the latest commit.

Comment: @evolutionxbox some-tag is the tag, but it's old tag, I want either the last commit or the tag in the last commit.

Comment: "the tag in the last commit" you mean the tag on the current commit, correct ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes, commit I'm currently running the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the list of tags that point at the current commit, use `git tag --points-at` :

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
git tag --points-at HEAD "v-*"  # only keep tags starting with 'v-'
```

If you want to have either a tag name or a commit hash, you can add a little scripting :

```
# in case there would be several tags: take the first one
name=$(git tag --points-at HEAD "v-*" | head -1)
# if no tag: get the short sha
if [ -z "$name" ]; then
   name=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
fi

# do something with $name ...
echo $name
```